# CSS: Show span inside <td>, on row hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I need to show a span inside a `<td>`, but only when the cointaner `<tr>` is hovered.

I have wrote this css rules, but they don't seem to work:

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > span.showOnHover {
    display:block!important;
}

.table-hover > tbody > tr > span.showOnHover {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Take a look to: https://jsfiddle.net/59ovvrvm/1/

I know I can do this with jquery, but any alternatives to do it only with css?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > td > span.showOnHover {
  display:block;
}

.table-hover > tbody > tr > td >  span.showOnHover {
  display: none;
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I just realize i forgot the `td`. Monday morning, I need some cofee. I can accept the answer on 10 min. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Hope it helps

```css
span{
  display:none
}

tr:hover > td > span{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table id="tableSample" class="table table-hover table-sindi table-sindi-select sindi-actions">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Usuario</th>
            <th>Comentario</th>            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Usuario 1</td>
        <td>
          Comentario 1
          <span class="showOnHover">!FOCUS</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Usuario 1</td>
        <td>
          Comentario 1
          <span class="showOnHover">!FOCUS</span>
        </td>
      </tr>         
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check That, No need of class in span,

```css
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover span{
        display:inline-block;
    }

    .table-hover > tbody > tr span {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<table id="tableSample" class="table table-hover table-sindi table-sindi-select sindi-actions">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Usuario</th>
            <th>Comentario</th>            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Usuario 1</td>
        <td>
          Comentario 1
          <span class="showOnHover">!FOCUS</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Usuario 1</td>
        <td>
          Comentario 1
          <span class="showOnHover">!FOCUS</span>
        </td>
      </tr>         
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: In real sample, there are other spans in the row cells. I need the class to apply the rul only on certain spans. But, do'nt worry, I found the problem thanks to PravenKumar solution. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

The problem is there

```
> span.showOnHover
```

You took a child-selector ">" which declares that only direct children of the ancestor get this style.
Just erase the child-selector and the style will get all descendants of your table-row.

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover span.showOnHover
```

and

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr span.showOnHover
```